What is the correct way to use JSON files stored server side in Next.js?
Right now I have a set of JSON files that I give global access to by putting them on an API endpoint on my web app. This makes it so several parts of the application can use the the data by simply making a fetch request to itself...
However since this data does not need to be publicly available and I feel like there is probably be a better way to do this since the website is the only entity that should use the data anyway.
I have tried to use the fs module to do this directly but if Im not wrong this needs to be used on the pages using the getStaticProps/getServerSideProps which would force me to rewrite that piece of code on every page that needs the data instead of just calling a prepared get-request function.
So is what is the correct way of doing it?

you can still make a function that imports using fs and just call that function, can make the path or subpath of some directory the arg

I haven't used next in a while but I'd like to know if you couldn't just import or require the json as well instead of using fs

@Max i get "cant resolve module error" when i tried this. The reasons seems to be that my app tried to use fs client-side but fs can only be used server-side. How should i write a function using fs so the page using the information gets rendered serverside?

yea if you want to use fs it should be on server, you can follow https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/server-components on how to make server component

but again depending on your environment and the nature of the data and the app, it may be beneficial to import the json file and redeploy. And since you're using next you can make use of https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration to have only certain pages regenerated according to how you configure it. Then you can just import the json and pass it to static props.

basically as for the difference between using fs and import/require I guess if you don't want to rebuild each time a file changes you should use fs.
As for abstracting the behaviour I think you could make a function however you need it, starting from the example on https://vercel.com/guides/loading-static-file-nextjs-api-route.
import { promises as fs } from 'fs';

export default async function Page() {
  const file = await fs.readFile(process.cwd() + '/app/data.json', 'utf8');
  const data = JSON.parse(file);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{data.title}</h1>
      <p>{data.content}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

Anywhere, you can define
const myReadFile = async (path: string) => {
  const file = await fs.readFile(process.cwd() + path, "utf8");
  const data = JSON.parse(file);
  return data;
};

And can call it in any component
export default async function Page() {
  const data = myReadFile("/app/data.json");

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{data.title}</h1>
      <p>{data.content}</p>
    </div>
  );
}


Char to char you may not save a lot, but it's still good to avoid have to rewrite the same thing, and in this case probably no disadvantages.
And you can extend the function with what you want, if you want to add types for what should be parsed, you can add a generic you would specify manually.
const myReadFileTyped = async <T,>(path: string): Promise<T> => {
  const file = await fs.readFile(process.cwd() + path, "utf8");
  const data: T = JSON.parse(file);
  return data;
};

then
type Data = {title:string, content:string};
const data = await myReadFileTyped<Data>("/app/data.json")

and use data in your component.
If you want to catch errors and return null or something else on exceptions, you can do
const myReadFileSafe = async <T,>(path: string): Promise<T | null> => {
  try {
    const file = await fs.readFile(process.cwd() + path, "utf8");
    const data: T = JSON.parse(file);
    return data;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    return null;
  }
};

and then
export default async function Page() {
  const data = await myReadFileSafe("/app/data.json");

  if (data === null) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{data.title}</h1>
      <p>{data.content}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

Then eventually you can add whatever logic you want, if you want to validate the parsed input with libraries you can.

You should add this compilerOption to your project's tsconfig.json
    "compilerOptions: {
       "resolveJsonModule": true,
    }

Then you can get strongly typed data structure from files which are privately held on your server, but become part of the javascript bundle ...
    import stuff from "./stuff.json";


Sure but i need it to be more dynamic, new files might be added during runtime and it needs to work for a folder of json files not only a singular one.
